# Why NodeJS block itself in The Poll Phase?

Tags: node.js

From [docs](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/):

> Phases Overview

1. timers: this phase executes callbacks scheduled by setTimeout() and
   setInterval().
2. pending callbacks: executes I/O callbacks deferred to
   the next loop iteration.
3. idle, prepare: only used internally.
4. poll:retrieve new I/O events; execute I/O related callbacks (almost all
   with the exception of close callbacks, the ones scheduled by timers,
   and setImmediate()); node will block here when appropriate.
5. check:
   setImmediate() callbacks are invoked here. close callbacks: some
6. close callbacks, e.g. socket.on('close', ...).

> Between each run of the event loop, Node.js checks if it is waiting
>   for any asynchronous I/O or timers and shuts down cleanly if there are
>   not any.

I cant understand the fourth bullet. And especially the line  "**node will block here when appropriate.**"

In what case Node will block itself and why?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As explained in this [section](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/#poll), poll phase calculates how long it would block and wait for I/O.
So in this phase it executes callbacks from timer if time threshold calculated in timers phase is crossed.

If not timer threshold is crossed and if the poll queue is not empty, the event loop will iterate through its queue of callbacks executing them synchronously until either the queue has been exhausted, or the system-dependent hard limit is reached.

If the poll queue is empty, one of two more things will happen:

1- If scripts have been scheduled by setImmediate(), the event loop will end the poll phase and continue to the check phase to execute those scheduled scripts.

2- If scripts have not been scheduled by setImmediate(), **the event loop will wait for callbacks to be added to the queue, then execute them immediately.**

Comment: what is system-dependent hard limit is reached?

Comment: copy pasted from the documentation without any real explanation